# View template not fully loading for a certain category [odd!]

Tags: categories, error

I'm coming across a pretty strange error.

I've recently added 2000 entries. Taken a while, but everything is cleaned up and seems to be working well, except for one thing I've found today.

The entries are all property listings. The are organised by categories that are County/County based. i.e parent category is the Country and the child category is the County.

For any entry that has 'Ireland' as the parent category, the 'view' template is not fully loading. It only loads part way and then stops. I kind of get half a page. The index page is fine.

I've switched on template debugging, but that is not loading either.

Not quite sure where to start finding out what the issue is!

Comment: I suggest stripping the template of all EE & add-on code. Then start piecing everything back together to see where it breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses. I had just set about breaking down the template, and start rebuilding to see where it breaks.

Luckily I noticed something early on. I have a tabbed content area, and whilst checking my half loaded page, I clicked into the final tab. This then displayed the debug and what appeared to be the rest of the page code all within the content area.

Check out that section on the view template and realised that I had an `if` statement that (potentially) displayed the postcode field, and it wasn't closed. This was throwing up the error, as none of the properties in Ireland had a postcode.

Doh! Luckily I spotted this early on! Cheers!

Comment: Feel free to tick this one off. It'll stop it bobbing back to the top of the pile every now and then. :)

Comment: Done! Must have missed this one! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Where to start troubleshooting: If there's not too many, I would

- take the entries with Ireland and take off the Ireland category.
- Then create 1 entry with Ireland as the category, but leave all the fields on the entry empty (other than required, but keep the data it as plain as possible).
- Then test, as it might be that there is a character in a field on the Ireland entries that is breaking the display.